Acceder a un miembro de clase padre desde un hijo de segunda generación
Quiero acceder a un miembro de la clase padre suprema desde una clase hija de segunda generación pero el miembro tiene el mismo nombre tanto en la clase padre inmediata como en el padre supremo
Estas son las clases:
Clase A
public class A {

  String a1 = "a1";
  String sameName = "sameName in A";

  public static void main(String... args){

    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();

    b.metodoB(); //a1
    c.metodoC(); //a1
    c.callSameNameInA(); //sameName in B **


  }
}

Clase B
public class B extends A {
  
  String sameName = "sameName in B";

  public void metodoB(){
    System.out.println(super.a1); //a1 
  }

}

Clase C
public class C extends B {
  
  public void metodoC(){
    System.out.println(super.a1); //a1 directamente desde C 
  }

  public void callSameNameInA(){
    System.out.println(super.sameName); //sameName in B **
  }


}

Como se puede ver, se puede llamar a un miembro de la clase suprema desde la clase hija aunque no sea hija directa:
System.out.println(super.a1); //desde la clase C
Mi pregunta es:
Como puedo acceder usando super a sameName de A desde la clase C?
Dicho de otra forma, quiero imprimir "sameName in A" desde la clase C y usando super
Gracias por vuestra ayuda :)

No parece ser posible.

Como dices, usar super.super no es posible. Java solo permite la herencia simple pero podemos tener un arbol familiar (simple) infinito. Para este caso "valdría" super.super pero si tenemos infinitos hijos para poder acceder al padre supremo deberíamos usar super.super.super.super ... infinitas veces y eso no es viable

He logrado replicar tu código, en mi experiencia en Java lo que tú haz pedido no se puede hacer usando super, lo he logrado hacer de otra manera si te interesa te dejo el código abajo solo modifique el método de la clase C
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class C extends B {

public void metodoC(){
    System.out.println(super.a1); //a1 directamente desde C 
  }

  public void callSameNameInA(){
    System.out.println(this.sameName); //sameName in B **
    
    A thizz = this;
    System.out.println(thizz.sameName); //sameName in A
    /*como C al final de todo hereda de la clase A se puede poner una
      instancia de la clase C en una variable tipo A, entonces
      cuando mandas a pedir la variable sameName desde una variable
      tipo A pero con instancia C manda el sistema manda a pedir 
      el valor de la direccion A.sameName en lugar de C.sameName(heredado)

      el codigo original que probar esta teoria fue este
      Field field = A.class.getDeclaredField("sameName");
      String value = (String) field.get(this);
      System.out.println(value);
     **/

  }
}


Muy buena tu respuesta. Es exactamente lo que buscaba.
Gracias por tu ayuda!

Parece un caso de herencia múltiple, lo cual no está permitido en Java (ver aquí para más detalles).
Si quieres acceder a "same name in A" desde una instancia de C, puedes hacerlo de diferentes modos, por ejemplo, creando una interfaz con el método getSameName(), luego implementas esa interfaz en la clase C, y desde un método que vamos a llamar getSameNameInA() invocas al método super.getSameName(). Ahí, super hará referencia al método de la clase A, dado que C extiende de B.
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo de un código funcional, aplicando lo que he explicado más arriba.
VER FIDDLE
Interfaces
interface NameInA {
    public String getSameName();    
}

interface NameInB {
    public String getSameNameInB();    
}

Clase A
public class A 
{
    String a1 = "a1";
    String sameName = "sameName in A";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.metodoB(); //a1

        C c= new C();
        c.metodoC(); //a1
        c.getSameNameInA();
        c.getSameNameInB();
    }

    public String getSameName()
    {
        return sameName;
    }
}

Clase B
public class B extends A 
{
    String sameName = "sameName in B";
    public void metodoB()
    {
        System.out.println(super.a1); //a1 
    }
    public String getSameNameInB()
    {
        System.out.println(sameName);
        return sameName;
    }
}

Clase C
class C extends B implements NameInA  
{
    public void metodoC()
    {
        System.out.println(super.a1); //a1 directamente desde C 
    }

    public String getSameNameInA() 
    {
        System.out.println(super.getSameName());
        return super.getSameName();
    }            
}

Si lo que aplica aquí es un caso de herencia múltiple, lo mejor es que en vez de hacer extender a C de la clase B, crees también una interfaz para el caso de "same name in B" y que implementes esas dos interfaces, eliminando el extends B, o también puedes manejarlo por medio de clases abstractas, eso ya dependerá del tipo de programa que quieres escribir y de cómo se relacionan los datos que representan esas clases entre sí.

No lo veo como una herencia múltiple entendiendo herencia múltiple cuando una clase extiende de varias clases padre.
No es el caso pero entiendo lo que quieres decir
Una forma más sencilla aún sería con un método en A que devuelva el valor de sameName y llamar a ese método directamente desde C.
Pero seguimos teniendo el problema de que si B tiene el mismo método con la misma firma (mismo nombre del método, tipo y orden de parámetros) éste tendrá preferencia sobre el método declarado en A
De todas formas es un ejemplo de estudio y no es para ningún caso real
Gracias por tu comentario!

@Doubtman el código hace exactamente lo que requieres al plantear la pregunta. Esto: Una forma más sencilla aún sería con un método en A que devuelva el valor de sameName y llamar a ese método directamente desde C. Pero seguimos teniendo el problema de que si B tiene el mismo método con la misma firma (mismo nombre del método, tipo y orden de parámetros) éste tendrá preferencia sobre el método declarado en A. Confirma precisamente que es un caso de herencia multiple. La dificultad que describes es el problema del diamante.

Vamos a ver, en principio, no me parece una buena idea, si estás "jugando" a conocer el lenguaje a fondo, fantástico, pero como algo a utilizar, lo tomaría muy con pinzas.
Empecemos por entender que pasa cuando extendemos una clase.
Una forma de pensarlo, es que tenemos, dentro de nuestra clase Hijo, un objeto de la clase Padre, y que, gracias a la magia del lenguaje, en determinadas circunstancias, Hijo se puede mimetizar, y parecer que es Padre.
Ahora bien, en Hijo, tenemos acceso directo a todos los atributos de la clase Padre, eso haría que en tu ejemplo, tengamos dos variables sameName (una del Padre y otra del Hijo), lo que puede ocasionar confusiones a la hora de utilizarlas.
Veamos como acceder (descartada la idea de super.super.x ya que no funiona:
public class A {
   String a1 = "a13b4";
   String sameName = "sameName in A";

     // agregamos este método, que es el que nos permitirá, mediante reflexión
     // acceder a "a1"
   public String getA() {
      return a1;
   }
}

public class C extends B {

   public void metodoC() {
      System.out.println( super.a1 );
   }

   public void callSameNameInA() {

        // esta linea, crea un array de metodos, y lo instancia, llamando a:
        // "getClass", que nos devuelve un objeto "class" de la clase actual
        // "getSuperclass()" le pedimos al objeto "class" que teniamos, que nos de
        // el objeto "class" de su padre, y a este, el de su padre
        // "getMethods" finalmente nos devuelve el array buscado
      Method hada[] = getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getMethods();

        // iteramos sobre el array, y cuando encontramos coincidencia con el nombre 
        // del método buscado, ejecutamos este, usando "invoke"
      for( Method x: hada ) {
         if( x.getName().equals( "getA" ) ) {
            try { // aca se invoca el metodo y se recibe el return 
               System.out.println( ( String ) x.invoke( this ) ); //sameName in B **
            }
            catch( IllegalAccessException
                    | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException e ) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


Como bien dices, es solo para conocer el lenguaje (estoy estudiando la OCP Java 11). No sabía que existía la clase Method ni que se podían listar los métodos de una clase pero me parece super interesante. Muchas gracias por tu comentario!

Un placer maestro!!.
